# Quantum state of a harmonic oscillator given energy and probability

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator, quantum-states

Hi I've been going through exercises without solution, so I would like to ask for some feedback if I am solving this right:

> A one-dimensional quantum harmonic oscillator with mass $m$ and frequency $\omega$ is in a state at $t=0$ described by a linear combination with real coefficients of the first two eigenstates of the Hamiltonian.

> Knowing that the probability of measuring the energy of the system to be $\frac{3}{2} \hbar \omega$ is equal to $\frac{4}{5}$, write down the state of the system.

I don't get why the energy $\frac{3}{2} \hbar \omega$ is given, my first thought was that it just meant that the first two states are: $| 0 \rangle$ with energy $\frac{1}{2} \hbar \omega$ and $| 1 \rangle$ with energy $\frac{3}{2} \hbar \omega$. But I thought this was implicit.

What makes me doubt is also that the initial state should be of the form: $| \psi \rangle = a_0 | 0 \rangle + a_1 | 1 \rangle $. The problem gives this information: $|a_1|^2 = \frac{4}{5}$, but is no way to know if $a_0$ and $a_1$ are positive or negative, right?

My answer would then be just: $| \psi \rangle = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} | 0 \rangle \pm \sqrt{\frac{4}{5}} | 1 \rangle $

But then there are other questions following and I feel I should have a definite answer for the initial state to continue. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't missing anything! You are certainly correct that someone only telling you the probabilities in this basis has not given you enough information to tell you the relative phases between the components in the superposition (your $\pm$ is one example of a phase ambiguity). And the energy is given just so you have to know offhand whether that energy refers to the first state, second state, etc (trying to quiz you twice in one question).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Then if I understood correctly what you said, the most general answer should be $| \psi \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} | 0 \rangle + \sqrt{\frac{4}{5}} e^{i\theta} | 1 \rangle $, right?

Comment: @mlp I can't answer your homework problems for you but I can say you understand it completely

Comment: It's not an homework, just exercises I am doing preparing for an upcoming exam. But thanks

Comment: @mlp not accusing you, I meant to say homework-style questions because they're off-limits on this site